# How can I delete these rows and columns that were created from excel?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this doubt. I have charged a sheet of excel from SQL Server 2008 and this shows all the data what contains the sheet. I wish to have the data that I want and I can save these records in a some table. But I need to know How 
I can delete all the data that I dont need rows and columns of the sheet.
Please I need your help.

I have it that I allow me import my sheet of Excel

```
select *  into #TBL_DATA  from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Microsoft\siac.xls; HDR=YES; IMEX=1', 
'select * from [Campo23$]')
```

This the image as shows in the query.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you don't want to import has a specific value in one of the columns you could use a `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement to filter the data.

For example: `WHERE colName <> 'value'`

Comment: Thanks for help me. This is when the values are statics. But if the values change then I could not do it   WHERE colName <> 'value' .

Comment: Thanks for your help. This would be if the values are statics. But when it not then this would not work . The head of my table from excel will not change